# c# class implements and inherits at the same time

Tags: c#, class, generics, inheritance, implementation

I want to declare a class that inherits a generic class and implements an interface, such as the following:

```
public class SortableObject
{
    int compare(SortableObejct obj);
}

public class List<T> where T is class
{
    public void add(T obj);
    public T peekCurrent();
}

public class SortedList<T> : List<T> where T : SortableObject, SortableObject
{
    public override int compare(SortableObejct obj);
}
```

I want `SortedList<T>` inherits from `List<T>` and implements from `SortableObject`, where `T` is a subclass from `SortableObject`. The c# compiler fails to compile such class; it seems to me that the grammar does not support this case.

Would anyone have met such difficulty and have a solution for it ?

Comment: You don't have an interface here, only two parent classes.  C# doesn't support multiple inheritance (inheriting from two or more parent classes).

Comment: My mistake, the first class is in fact an interface.

Answer (score 3):

Just make `SortableObject` implement an interface:

```
public interface ISortableObject
{
    int compare(SortableObejct obj);
}

public class SortableObject : ISortableObject
{
    int compare(SortableObejct obj);
}

public class SortedList<T> : List<T> where T : SortableObject
```

This will ensure that if it is in fact a `SortableObject` it has implemented the `ISortableObject` interface.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your interface an interface, rather than a class, to start with:

```
public interface ISortableObject
{
    int compare(ISortableObject obj);
}
```

Next, your syntax for declaring `List<T>` wasn't quite right; you weren't declaring the generic constraint properly.  It should be:

```
public class List<T> 
    where T : class
{
    public void add(T obj);
    public T peekCurrent();
}
```

Finally, to have a class inherit from a class, implement an interface, and also add generic constraints, you need to do them in that order.  You can't add the interface implementation after the generic constraints are defined.

```
public class SortedList<T> : List<T>, ISortableObject
    where T : ISortableObject
{
    public override int compare(ISortableObject obj);
}
```

Comment: Cool, that's the solution I was looking for. All simply.

Comment: Thanks, that exactly answer my question.